# mvvmcross MvxActionBasedTableViewSource as groupped table

Tags: ios, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I use **MvxActionBasedTableViewSource** for my custom binding on common grids.

Func **CellCreator** is really great and everything works fine with that.

But. What way is it expected to deal with **groupped tables**?
I need some dynamic binding with them.

So, does that mean that I should *implement that logic by my own* and CellCreator can not be used for such behaviour anyhow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MvxActionBasedTableViewSource` is designed for simple tables only - so cannot be used for grouping without some changes - e.g. via inheritance or copy and paste.

For a list of available TableViewSources, see [What class to inherit from for bound table source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986207/what-class-to-inherit-from-for-bound-table-source/16986461#16986461)

For an example of grouping, see [Creating UITable with section using Mono touch and slodge mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528193/creating-uitable-with-section-using-mono-touch-and-slodge-mvvmcross/13528955#13528955) (the code is out of date, but the principles are still the same)

Comment: I see. But in meaning of binding, generally, for MvxActionBasedTableViewSource (and MvxStandardTableViewCell) there is no difference either the table is grouped or not, right?

Comment: Sorry. I'm afraid that one sentence about 'the meaning of binding' doesn't really mean much to me. The `ActionBased` table source does not support grouping - so yes, that is a very significant difference. The best I can suggest is that you try taking a look at the links provided, try building a grouped data source, and then come back with specific detailed questions if you hit challenges. The good news is that it sounds like you've already got a good, strong grasp of the concepts, and a good, strong idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Actually, I've tried the inheritance and everything looks pretty simple and clear: overriding of typical methods necessary for sections to be defined (like "SectionFor", "RowsInSection", "NumberOfSections" etc) as well as GetItemAt to find correct item from my custom datastructure.
So, everything works like a charm. Thank you!