# Grouped ListView with Implicit Template Selection in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an app I have developed using native technologies across iOS, Android, and WP.  I began porting over to C# using Xamarin and stumbled across MvvmCross.  One of the core features of the app is a Group ListView with several different custom cell types.

Question #1: Does MvvmCross have a cross platform Group ListView control?  I found [this](http://deapsquatter.blogspot.com/2013/02/mvvmcrossdeapextensions.html), but it appears to be only Android.

Question #2: Is there a way to do implicit template selection in MvvmCross?  Right now the implementation of these ListViews is pretty different platform to platform.  On WP, I found an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113152/Applying-Data-Templates-Dynamically-by-Type-in-WP7) to do implicit template selection.  Is something like this possible with MvxListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of the samples show how to use cell type selection. See:

- polymorphic lists in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- grouped lists in the session list views in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference - this is analysed in [Creating UITable with section using Mono touch and slodge mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528193/creating-uitable-with-section-using-mono-touch-and-slodge-mvvmcross/13528955#13528955)
- a simple polymorphic list in the pet shop in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/MonoTouchCellTutorial

For more on available table source base classes see [What class to inherit from for bound table source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986207/what-class-to-inherit-from-for-bound-table-source/16986461#16986461)

For another user's ideas on grouped tables, also see their comments in [mvvmcross MvxActionBasedTableViewSource as groupped table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213754/mvvmcross-mvxactionbasedtableviewsource-as-groupped-table)